# Can I install packages to external SD card on Termux in Android?

Tags: external-sd, linux, android-versions, termux

I am using Termux in my Android device and it is awesome. I've installed it from Google Play. Now the packages that I install using the command `pkg install ...`, install those to the internal storage. Since my internal storage space is running low, I am thinking to install these packages to the external SD card. Can I do it? Thank you.

Comment: You can bind mount a directory from external SD card to `/data/data/com.termux/files` using FUSE or `sdcardfs` with correct permissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't.

The packages you install using `pkg install`, which is actually a wrapper for the frontend of the famous Debian Package Manager, APT. APT downloads packages provided by Termux and installs them. So the packages are just [Debian packages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deb_(file_format)). Witha bit of Googling and/or digging, you'll find that **file paths are hardcoded**, i.e., they'll always be extracted (installed) into `/data/data/com.termux/files/usr`.

Possible tricks are, apparently, possible. However it's not recommended to try any as Termux is highly similar to a real Linux environment, which means any bad SELinux context or wrong permission can cause programs to malfunction.

Answer: Try to free up your internal storage if you plan to install more packages in Termux, instead of thinking about installing the packages to elsewhere.