# Can the Termux environment be put on an external SD card?

Tags: external-sd, installation, termux

I would like to install my termux environment (usr folder) to an SD card. is this possible?

I have seen this post [Can I install packages to external SD card on Termux in Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/199259/can-i-install-packages-to-external-sd-card-on-termux-in-android). From what I understand the problems mentioned there is only if you want to install individual packaged to the SD card. I'm looking to install the whole usr folder.

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/219995

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your device is rooted, you can do it, but it is a little tricky. (You may need to use another terminal app or work in failsafe of termux).

1. Create an `ext4` partition on the SD card. (This can be a 2nd partition).
2. Make a new folder where you want to mount the new partition on. (For example in your home folder add a folder called `ext4-fs`)
3. In termux mount the partition (I'm assuming a 2nd partition). You need to know the path to the device. I have found it to be `/dev/block/mmcblk1p2` but this may be different on your device. `mount /dev/block/mmcblk1p2 /data/data/com.termux/files/home/ext4-fs`.
4. Copy the `usr` folder from termux `/data/data/com.termux/files/usr` to the new mounted partition.

**From here on you will need to use commands that are in `/system/bin/`. (And may need to use failsafe mode or an other terminal app).**

5. Rename the `usr` folder to something like `usr-old`. `/system/bin/mv /data/data/com.termux/files/usr /data/data/com.termux/files/usr-old`.
6. Make symlink to the `usr` folder that's now on the new partition. `ln -s /data/data/com.termux/files/home/ext4-fs/usr /data/data/com.termux/files/usr`. This will now be your termux usr folder which is linked to the folder on the sd card. (You can force a symlink even if `usr` already exists with `ln -sfn`)

Now you can delete the old `usr` folder (That we renamed `usr-old`).

Now termux uses the symlinked folder that is on your SD card for all that needs the `usr` folder which is the whole termux environment.

**Every time you take out the SD card and reinsert it you will need to remount the partition.**

Comment: Trying this on a rooted device but on step 6 getting `ln: cannot create hard link from '/data/data/com.termux/files/home/ext4-fs/usr' to '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr': cross-device link`

Comment: @MiguelMota You need to make a symlink with option `-s`. (See the edited step #6)

Comment: Thank you for your help, but when I tried:
`mount /dev/block/mmcblk1p2 /data/data/com.termux/files/home/ext4-fs`
in my termux shell, I received a "permission denied" message.
I can do a mount with `tsudo`, but then I cannot access the ext4-fs file without being root.
I am using Android 6.0 and a v0.79 Termux.
If you have any suggestions or solutions I will be grateful.

Comment: @PB As root, do `chown -R <your-termux-uid>:<termux-gid> <mount-point>`. The mount point in your case is `/data/data/com.termux/files/home/ext4-fs`

Comment: @Sruly But in my case mount point doesn’t persists after reboot ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was SELinux. I resolved by installing "The SELinux Switch" and then putting in the "permissive" mode.
Now I can mount with root and access in Termux WITHOUT root!