# Can I mount /data/data/(app_name)/ on external sd card?

Tags: applications, external-sd, permissions, mount, android-10

Can I mount `/data/data/com.termux/` folder on external sd card? My phone is rooted Android 10 and running low of internal storage.

As I read from [How to bind mount a folder inside /sdcard with correct permissions?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/217741/how-to-bind-mount-a-folder-inside-sdcard-with-correct-permissions) mounting to `/sdcard` requires permission to mount because `/sdcard` is emulated from `/data/media/0` and `/data/data/` is not.

And from [Can the Termux environment be put on an external SD card?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/228443/can-the-termux-environment-be-put-on-an-external-sd-card) it can mount `/data/data/com.termux/` using `ln -s` because `ext4` support links while `fat` doesn't.

I don't know how `/data/data/` directory works but is it possible to mount `/data/data/com.termux/files/home/` directory to external sd card without formatting it as adoptable storage or making `ext4` partition?

Comment: Yes. Create a loop file in SD card and mount it to `/data/data/com.termux/files/home`.

Answer (score 2):

- create a file in MicroSD Card. make sure the file is not too large for fat32 file size limitation

  ```
  busybox dd if=/dev/zero seek=4294967295 bs=1 count=0 of=/mnt/media_rw/6DE8-1BC6/loop.img
  ```
- create a file system (confirm with y)

  ```
  /system/bin/mke2fs -t ext4 /mnt/media_rw/6DE8-1BC6/loop.img
  ```
- loop mount the file to existing directory

  ```
  mkdir -p /data/data/com.termux/files/home/ubuntu20-fs
  busybox mount /mnt/media_rw/6DE8-1BC6/loop.img /data/data/com.termux/files/home/ubuntu20-fs
  ```

---

**UPDATE:**

that works only for busybox with largefile support. according to user [Jtnqr](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/231478) and user [Hmm](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/232298) you may still facing some trouble. the following is exactly the same example like above but with screenshots
**** * * stop reading here * * ****

only one extra step is copying files/usr into loop file before mounting

---

- create a file in MicroSD Card

  ```
  ls -la /data/data/com.termux/files
  su
  mkdir /storage/26B7-11F7/com.termux
  cd /storage/26B7-11F7/com.termux
  busybox dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M count=4095 of=usr.img
  ```

  [image: 2020-12-27_22_39_23.png]

---

- create a file system (confirm with y)

  ```
  /system/bin/mke2fs -t ext4 usr.img
  ```

  [image: 2020-12-27_22_41_49.png]

---

- copy `files/usr` into loop file before mounting

  ```
  mkdir -p tmp/usr
  busybox mount usr.img tmp/usr

  df -h | grep /dev/loop
  grep termux /proc/mounts

  busybox cp -acv /data/data/com.termux/files/usr tmp
  df -h | grep /dev/loop
  ```

  [image: 2020-12-27_22_53_15.png]

---

- loop mount the file to existing directory

  ```
  umount tmp/usr
  busybox mount usr.img /data/data/com.termux/files/usr
  df -h | grep /dev/loop
  exit
  ls -la /data/data/com.termux/files/usr
  ```

  [image: 2020-12-27_22_57_21.png]

---

the same can be repeated for other directories. you can loop mount another `home.img` file into `files/home` to extend termux storage

reason for splitting into multiple files is fat32 file size limitation < 4 GB

Comment: [Busybox-1.29.2-YDS-UNIVERSAL.zip](https://github.com/yashdsaraf/bb-bot/releases/download/v1.29.2-YDS-201808012015/Busybox-1.29.2-YDS-UNIVERSAL.zip)

Comment: im trying to do the same and if i run `busybox dd if=/dev/zero seek=4294967295 bs=1 count=0 of=/mnt/media_rw/26B7-11F7/com.termux/loop.img` it gives me `dd: /mnt/media_rw/26B7-11F7/com.termux/loop.img: Invalid argument`