# Cant' mount loop device

Tags: external-sd, file-system, mount, command-line

After I format the `loop.img` (formatted as `ext4`) I can mount it no problem.

But when I'm trying to remount `loop.img` from external sdcard to `/data/data/com.termux/home/ubuntu20-fs/`
always throw invalid argument , I already tried using busybox too.

```
mount -t ext4 -o loop /dev/block/loop3 /data/data/com.termux/files/home/ubuntu20-fs/
mount: '/dev/block/loop3'->'/data/data/com.termux/files/home/ubuntu20-fs/': Invalid argument
```

Does anyone know what happened?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2CmY.jpg)

[dmesg | grep avc](https://pastebin.com/Zhpxn4iy)

[Strace of busybox mount with "-t" argument](https://pastebin.com/3CJguPbs)

`losetup`:

```
NAME  SIZELIMIT  OFFSET  AUTOCLEAR  RO  BACK-FILE  DIO  LOG-SEC
...
/dev/block/loop3  0  0  0  0  /mnt/media_rw/6DE8-1BC6/loop.img  0  512
```

`blkid | grep loop`:

```
/dev/block/loop3: UUID="0746ba9e-fc09-4a32-8b5f-49aee9096cf7" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4"
```

Comment: @beeshyams IrfanLatif anyone can confirm this behavior android 10? is this a magisk selinux bug maybe?

Comment: I don't know if that is the correct logcat or not

Comment: @alecxs everything related to mounting filesystems works as expected on Android 10 too. No abnormal behavior. If the issue is related to SELinux, `setenforce 0` should fix it. Also `dmesg | grep avc` should show the related denial log entry. @Jtnqr run mount with `strace` and share log.

Comment: @Jtnqr are you typing commands from termux touchpad, or do you use script, copy & paste or other keyboard?

Comment: @alexcs I ran termux using my phone touchscreen, no script. The output I copypaste from termux except strace I'm using the `-o` argument.

Comment: so no invisible chars and no wrong line endings. could it be that file system is unmounted dirty? does it make a difference with *-t ext4 -o ro,noexec,noload,noatime*

Comment: wdym? Is this dirty unmount `umount /mnt/ubuntu20-fs`?

Comment: i mean by any chance the ext4 journal is dirty for unknown reason