# com.termux linked or mounted on SD (Root Available)

Tags: sd-card, mount, termux

So I'm trying to get more space into my termux to download and use
I'm trying to mount the folder onto the SD does anyone know how to already or done it?
I've seen that it isn't possible but I don't see why wouldn't it be especially with root

Comment: It's definitely possible. Create a loop file on SD card and mount it wherever you want.

Comment: Can you tell me how?

Comment: The location of the termux by default is/data/data/com.termux/ I made a folder on my SD /storage/26B7-11F7/com.termux/

Comment: check xda @alecxs

Comment: check the above link again, have extended my answer especially for you, just copy & paste the commands