# Put Termux environment on external SD card

Tags: external-sd, installation, mount, terminal, termux

Following [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/228444), I formated my sdcard as ext4-fs.

Then tried mounting the sdcard into termux home as the link above says

```
mount /dev/block/mmcblk1p2 /data/data/com.termux/files/home/ext4-fs
```

I get error **mount: bad /etc/fstab: No such file or directory**

I could only mount the partition with root using **su** command, only then the **mount** command doesn't give error.

Mounting the partition with **su** from terminal *or* with app like **Link2Sd** (which also uses root) makes the mount point (i.e where the partition is mounted) unreadable for Termux.

What am I missing?

He (the author of the answer above) even went further to create a *symlink* to Termux $PREFIX using another terminal app which is **impossible** without root also **as** thus also not readable by Termux which even complicates everything

I think this should be possible, what am I doing wrong pls

Comment: That's expected. `mount` never works without root (or at least [CAP_SYS_ADMIN](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) to be more precise). Mounting a filesystem is a privileged action not meant to be performed by ordinary users. // You need to set proper permissions; owner, group, mode and SELinux context on the mount point to make it accessible to non-privileged apps like Termux. Run `ls -lZ .` in Termux HOME directory to get these parameters.

Comment: Hi @Irfan thanks for looking to my question. Changing the   owner, group to uid of Termux (gotten from **id** command) and also chmod 777 doesn't help. I get **Permission denied**. What's that with SELinux context, please any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The problem was SELinux. I resolved by installing "The SELinux Switch" and then putting in the "permissive" mode. Now I can mount with root and access in Termux WITHOUT root!