# How to move the entire termux to sdcard

Tags: root-access, sd-card, terminal, termux

i have seen multiple posts but non helped.
i have root access and i want to put the whole termux on my 32GB sdcard because i have a very limited internal storage (8GB) and most of it is used by the system. Please help asap

i have seen this but i didnt understand how to do it
https://android.stackexchange.com/a/228444/44325

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Looks like you have found a similar question [Can the Termux environment be put on an external SD card?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/228444/44325). Could you [edit] and explain what didn't work?